# Avoiding for loop and try to utilize collection APIs instead (performance)

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I have a piece of code from an old project.

The logic (in a high level) is as follows:
The user sends a series of `{id,Xi}` where id is the primary key of the object in the database.
The aim is that the database is updated but the series of `Xi` values is always **unique**.

I.e. if the user sends `{1,X1}` and in the database we have `{1,X2},{2,X1}` the input should be rejected otherwise we end up with duplicates i.e. `{1,X1},{2,X1}` i.e. we have `X1` twice in different rows.

In lower level the user sends a series of custom objects that encapsulate this information.

Currently the implementation for this uses "brute-force" i.e. continuous for-loops over input and jdbc resultset to ensure uniqueness.

I do not like this approach and moreover the actual implementation has subtle bugs but this is another story.

I am searching for a better approach, both in terms of coding and performance.

What I was thinking is the following:

- Create a `Set` from the user's input list. If the `Set` has different size than list, then user's input has duplicates.Stop there.
- Load data from jdbc.
- Create a `HashMap<Long,String>` with the user's input. The key is the primary key.
- Loop over result set. If `HashMap` does not `contain` a key with the same value as ResultSet's row id then add it to `HashMap`
- In the end get `HashMap`'s values as a `List`.If it contains duplicates reject input.

This is the algorithm I came up.
Is there a better approach than this? (I assume that I am not erroneous on the algorithm it self)

Comment: Why not just use a unique constraint on the column in the database?

Comment: I can not modify the database at this point.I can only modify the old code

Comment: Wait, are you saying `{1, X2}` is a string value in a single column in the database?

Comment: No the table is a table with A LOT of columns (it is a huge schema).This is only a small part I am talking about I am interested in fixing for a specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't change the database, as stated in the comments. I would probably extend out your Set idea. Create a `HashMap<Long, String>` and put all of the items from the database in it, then also create a `HashSet<String>` with all of the values from your database in it.

Then as you go through the user input, check the key against the hashmap and see if the values are the same, if they are, then great you don't have to do anything because that exact input is already in your database.

If they aren't the same then check the value against the HashSet to see if it already exists. If it does then you have a duplicate.

Should perform much better than a loop.

#### Edit:

For multiple updates perform all of the updates on the `HashMap` created from your database then once again check the `Map`'s value set to see if its' size is different from the key set.

There might be a better way to do this, but this is the best I got.

Comment: I think this has a subtle bug in the second part of the logic.When the check against the `HashSet` is done to see if the value exist, if I consider the existense as a duplicate,I am not allowing the user to insert a reversed tupple. I.e. in the DB `{1,X1},{2,X2}` and user input `{1,X2},{2,X1}`. This is allowed but your algorithm will reject it.Right?

Comment: @user384706 Yes that is correct, I didn't know you wanted multiple updates to be able to process at once. Let me see if I can make this work.

Answer (score 3):

Purely from performance point of view , why not let the database figure out that there are duplicates ( like `{1,X1},{2,X1}` ) ? Have a unique constraint in place in the table and then when the update statement fails by throwing the exception , catch it and deal with what you would want to do under these input conditions. You may also want to run this as a single transaction just if you need to rollback any partial updates. Ofcourse this is assuming that you dont have any other business rules driving the updates that you havent mentioned here.

With your algorithm , you are spending too much time iterating over `HashMap`s and `List`s to remove duplicates IMHO.

Comment: just bear in mind the database is not magic, you can end up with quite the performance problem if you push all such functionality onto the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for a database-side solution. Assuming a table with the columns `id` and `value`, you should make a list with all the "values", and use the following SQL:

```
select count(*) from tbl where value in (:values);
```

binding the `:values` parameter to the list of values however is appropriate for your environment. (Trivial when using Spring JDBC and a database that supports the `in` operator, less so for lesser setups. As a last resort you can generate the SQL dynamically.) You will get a result set with one row and one column of a numeric type. If it's 0, you can then insert the new data; if it's 1, report a constraint violation. (If it's anything else you have a whole new problem.)

If you need to check for every item in the user input, change the query to:

```
select value from tbl where value in (:values)
```

store the result in a set (called e.g. `duplicates`), and then loop over the user input items and check whether the value of the current item is in `duplicates`.

This should perform better than snarfing the entire dataset into memory.

Comment: There is one issue here.The user is allowed to send data in batches.And the user is allowed to send `{1,X2},{2,X1}` and in the DB it is `{1,X1},{2,X2}`.I.e. send the reverse tupple.So after the update the data are still unique.This approach does not allow for this, right?

Comment: @user384706: Nope, not really. You could modify it by using transactions. Start a transaction, do the update, **then** check for duplicates using something like `select value, count(*) from tbl where value in (:values) group by value`. If all the counts are 1, no duplicates were introduced and you can commit the transaction. If any of them is more than 1, the corresponding value is a duplicate and you should abort the transaction. Depending on how detailed your error reporting has to be, you can either reduce or will have to increase the complexity.